# define a function in JavaScript and not bind it to window object

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

I want to define a function like below and use it inside Jquery `$(document).ready`;

```
function pad2(number) {

     return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number

}
```

I am not sure I am doing it right here. I don't want to bind the function to window object. what kind of way should I follow here to do the following thing right;

```
    $(function(){

        alert(pad2(eval("10")));

    });

    function pad2(number) {

         return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work ... you can use [self executing functions](http://www.jspatterns.com/self-executing-functions/) to control object/function scope.

```
(function() {
    function pad2(number) {

         return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number

    }

    $(function(){

        alert(pad2(eval("10")));

    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need `eval`, but yes, your way will indeed create a global, i.e. bind to the window object. Try:

```
$(function(){

    function pad2(number) {
         return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number
    }
    alert(pad2("10"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function a member of another object, like this:

```
var MyObj = {};

MyObj.pad2 = function pad2(number) {
     return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
}

$(function(){
    alert(MyObj.pad2(10));
});
```

Comment: this is the one I am trying to remember.

Comment: -1 didn't solve the problem; still exposed something to the global scope

Comment: The OP poster didn't say that they trying to avoid binding anything to the global scope, just the function, which this accomplishes.